# My Touch pad is not working properly (keeps jumping to the recycle bin)

Tags: touchpad, acer, tap-to-click

Hi guys i have been using Ubuntu on my desktop at work for a while now, but it seems like a really cool OS so i decided to install it on a Acer V5-572 Laptop.

The only thing I need help is the touch pad, it is really unresponsive and it jumps to the bottom left a lot of the time meaning i keep opening the recycle bin a lot. When I had Windows 10 on this system i had this exact problem and I fixed it by installing the drivers for the touch pad, but i cant seem to find the drivers.

Comment: Do you know what the trackpad's model is?

Comment: im not 100% sure but i have looked at the other guides and i cant find any drivers but i thin this is it "Acer Aspire V5-572P V5-573P V7-581PG"

Comment: That's your laptop model.  Try this: open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and then `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.

Comment: Cheers mate, it works!

Comment: Great! I'll put it as an answer.

Comment: Im sorry but the touch pad does fell more responsive but it still jumps to the trashcan ! grrrrr

Comment: Hmm. Try rebooting.

Comment: Yeah as soon I download and installed the driver i rebooted but the mouse still jumps, when i click on the left click button.

Comment: Let me see if turning off tap to click fixers this.

Comment: Nope still having this problem :/

Comment: hmm. Give me a bit and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I did read that Legacy boot has been know to casue this problem so im reinstalling on UFEI

Comment: I know what is causing the problem but i dont know the fix, basically the touch pad and the click buttons are the same so when i click using the left click the mouse flys over to the bottom left, is there any way of just disabling the bottom part of the touch pad?

Comment: You could see if the command `xinput` shows anything. (`xinput enable/disable devID` for control).

Comment: It shows up as a "SynPS/2 Synaptics keybaord" i have just right now disable and then enabled it and now it jumps to the top right near the power button !

Comment: Your trackpad? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Yeah my bad its a SynPS/2 Synaptics touchpad, but after disabling and enable it now jumps to the top right

Comment: Well that's certainly interesting. I'm really not sure what you could do.

Comment: Yeah i mean now its less annoying because it just brings up the power bar and not the trash can but still thanks for your time mate.

Comment: I have the same problem on an Asus Zenbook UX305 ("Elan Touchpad") on 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had this type of problem.
I fixed was by changing Touchpad Settings from `Advanced` to `Basic` on the Bios menu.
It will work for me try it maybe works for you too.