# Acer Swift 3 touchpad phantom clicks on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, acer

I got a new Acer Swift 3 and put Ubuntu 18.04 on it. Sometimes it will click on things when I think I'm scrolling.

I'm new to Ubuntu. How do I begin to figure out if this is a hardware issue or a software issue such as with the touchpad driver?

Under the output of `xinput --list-props 10` it says `libinput Tapping` so that means that no proprietary drivers are being used, right? Is there a proprietary driver? I didn't see one in Software & Updates.

I thought earlier versions of Ubuntu had two settings, one for pointer speed and one for click speed. What happened to that?

```
stephanie@swiftbetty:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYN1B7F:00 06CB:CD41 Touchpad             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD User Facing: HD User Facing            id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
stephanie@swiftbetty:~$ xinput --list-props 10
Device 'SYN1B7F:00 06CB:CD41 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (277): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (278): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (279):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (280):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (281):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (282):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (283):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (284):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (285):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (286):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (287):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (288):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (289):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (290):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (291):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (292): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (293):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (294):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (295):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (296):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (297): -0.115108
    libinput Accel Speed Default (298): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (299): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (300): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (262): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (263):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (264):    0, 0
    Device Node (265):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (266):    1739, 52545
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (301):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (302):   1
stephanie@swiftbetty:~$
```

Comment: I tried `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and it seems this is now using the Synaptics driver. Let's see if this is better.

Comment: Nope. This driver is worse.

Comment: mya be helps you this https://askubuntu.com/questions/727257/my-touch-pad-is-not-working-properly-keeps-jumping-to-the-recycle-bin/1341178#1341178