# touch pad not working Acer swift 3 with ubuntu 18.04.03

Tags: touchpad, acer

First of all, I have tried all the online SO solutions like adding those text in my grub but nothing working. Here is output of `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse                       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:CD40 Mouse               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:CD40 Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Acer Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ HD WebCam: HD WebCam                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Intel HID events                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Check out this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/727257/my-touch-pad-is-not-working-properly-keeps-jumping-to-the-recycle-bin

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading the version of Kernel to latest I simply did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. (Turn off secure boot by setting a password in BIOS).